# FIle.Copy() ouput An unhandled exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Tags: c#, windows, file

I'm trying to use Copy method in File class but I can't get it works it print always the same exception , I have tried to create the folder in Desktop and I'm trying to uncheck the read only attribute in folder but no chance to do this because after saving the property , the folder still always with read only property .

This is my code :

```
 mypath = "D:\\Test\\image1.png";
 folder = "C:\\Users\\user1\\Desktop\\folder"
 DirectoryInfo directory = Directory.CreateDirectory(folder);
 File.Copy(directory.FullName, mypath);
```

I've searched on the community for a solution but any of theses solution works for me :

- [C# UnauthorizedAccessException in File.Copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18554108/c-sharp-unauthorizedaccessexception-in-file-copy)
- [C# unauthorizedAccessException when doing File.Copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15662124/c-sharp-unauthorizedaccessexception-when-doing-file-copy)
- [File.Copy throws UnauthorizedAccessException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38841195/file-copy-throws-unauthorizedaccessexception)
- [UnauthorizedAccessException in file copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59661639/unauthorizedaccessexception-in-file-copy)

[image]

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: A user on has access to his own user account files  "C:\\Users\\user1\\Desktop\\folder".  If you need access to other users files than put the files in a location where all users have access like a network dirve.

Comment: `File.Copy(directory.FullName,...)`. You're trying to copy a directory using `File.Copy`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos No , I'm trying to copy file from folder to another folder created recently

Comment: Your code says `copy the folder over the file`

Comment: @jdweng I have admin privileges

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos , but my object is to copy file from folder to another folder , maybe my code was wrong and this is possible

Comment: The first link "C# UnauthorizedAccessException in File.Copy" has the same issue - trying to copy a folder into a file.

Comment: Admin doesn't work when running in VS unless you open VS with shortcut and select RunAsAdmin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy method can't be used with folder name arguments, and also your argument order is wrong.

Definition of the method is

```
public static void Copy (string sourceFileName, string destFileName);
```

both arguments should be filenames, not directories.

So you can use

```
File.Copy(mypath, folder+"\\" + Path.GetFileName(mypath));
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to copy a directory using [File.Copy(sourceFilename,destFilename)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.copy?view=net-6.0#system-io-file-copy(system-string-system-string)). On top of that, the destination can't be a directory path

> **destFileName** String
>
> The name of the destination file. This cannot be a directory or an existing file.

To copy a file into a new directory you need to construct the new full file path and reverse the order of the arguments:

```
Directory.CreateDirectory(folder);

...

var fileName=Path.GetFileName(myPath);
var destPath=Path.Combine(folder,fileName)

File.Copy(myPath,destPath);
```